Problem extracting a line from a buffer readed from a file descriptor
Well, i am trying to create a program that reads from a file descriptor piece by piece (defined as BUFFER_SIZE), until it finds a '\n' or the EOF. The problem its i am getting stuck in a infinite loop, which i try to address the cause without success, (you can notice the printf's all around the code). note: for this assignment i am only allowed to use a limited number of standard functions so to use realloc i have to implement my own, same with strlen and others. (assume that they are correct). ALLOWED FUNCTIONS: WRITE, READ, MALLOC AND FREE. There is the code:
void    *ft_realloc(void *ptr, size_t oldsize, size_t size)
{
void    *new;
size_t  minsize;

if (size == 0)
{
    free(ptr);
    return (NULL);
}
if (ptr == NULL)
    return (malloc(size));
new = malloc(size);
if (!new)
   return (NULL);
minsize = size;
if (oldsize < size)
   minsize = oldsize;
memcpy(new, ptr, minsize);
while (size - oldsize != 0)
   ((char *)new)[oldsize++] = '\0';
free(ptr);
return (new);
}

int find_newline_eof(char *buffer)
{
int i;

i = 0;
if (!buffer)
    return (-1);
while (buffer[i])
{
    if (buffer[i] == '\n')
        return (i);
    i++;
}
return (-1);
}

char    *extract_line(char **buffer, int newline_pos)
{
char    *line;
int     remaining_len;
//in terms of params, to newline be -1, means that we reach EOF 
 without '\n'
if (!*buffer)
    return (NULL);
if (newline_pos == -1)
    newline_pos = ft_strlen(*buffer);
line = malloc(newline_pos + 1);
if (!line)
    return (NULL);
memcpy(line, *buffer, newline_pos);
line[newline_pos] = '\0';
if ((*buffer)[newline_pos] == '\n')
    newline_pos++;
printf("reached EXTRACT_LINE, line: (%s)\n", line);
return (NULL); // The function reaches HERE, the error is beyond.
remaining_len = ft_strlen(*buffer + newline_pos);
// memmove safer against overlapping than memcpy
memmove(*buffer, *buffer + newline_pos, remaining_len + 1);
*buffer = ft_realloc(*buffer, ft_strlen(*buffer), remaining_len + 1);
if (!*buffer)
{
    free(line);
    return (NULL);
}
return (line);
}

int read_newpiece(int fd, char **buffer)
{
int         bytes_readed;
char        current_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
char        *new_buffer;

bytes_readed = read(fd, current_buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
if (bytes_readed <=0) //SAFE CHECKS
    return (bytes_readed);
current_buffer[bytes_readed] = '\0';
//printf("entered here!\n");
//return (bytes_readed);
if (!*buffer)
{
    *buffer = malloc(1);
    if (!*buffer)
        return (-1);
    (*buffer)[0] = '\0'; // Initialize as an empty string
}
new_buffer = ft_realloc(*buffer, ft_strlen(*buffer), 
ft_strlen(*buffer) + bytes_readed + 1);
if (!new_buffer)
    return (-1);
*buffer = new_buffer;
strncat(*buffer, current_buffer, bytes_readed);
return (bytes_readed);
}

char    *get_next_line(int fd)
{
static char *buffer = NULL;
char        *line; //returned value
int         newline_index; //position where we find the EOF or '\n';

if (fd < 0 || BUFFER_SIZE <= 0)
    return (NULL);
if (!buffer)
{
    buffer = malloc(1);
    if (!buffer)
        return (NULL);
    buffer[0] = '\0';
}
newline_index = -1; //-1 (NOT FOUND)
while (newline_index == -1 && read_newpiece(fd, &buffer) > 0)
{
    printf("buffer after read: /%s/\n", buffer);
    newline_index = find_newline_eof(buffer);
    printf("newline index: %d\n", newline_index);
    //return (NULL);
}
if (newline_index == -1 && !buffer)
   return (NULL);
line = extract_line(&buffer, newline_index);
printf("extracted line: ///%s///\n", line);
return (NULL);
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
int     fd;
char    *line;

if (ac < 2)
    return (write(1, "Usage: ./a.out <filename>\n", 27));
fd = open(av[1], O_RDONLY);
if (fd <= -1) //SAFE CHECKS
    return (write(1, "error opening file\n", 20));

while ((line = get_next_line(fd)) != NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n", line);
    free (line);
}
close (fd);
return (0);
}

the realloc take three params, the original buffer, the length of this buffer and the new desired size. It copies the entire buffer to a new one if the size > length, and copies (size) characters if the size if size < length. I appreciate any suggestion on any aspect of the code, but mainly to resolve the problem
i try to identify the issue step by step with aid of printf to check the value in some contexts

i am only allowed to use a limited number of standard functions  Could you edit your question and add the functions you're allowed to use?

This would be a good opportunity to learn to use a debugger. You should be able to single-step through the code to see where it's getting stuck in the loop.

Also, for code such as write(1, "error opening file\n", 20), instead of relying on counting bytes, use something like static const char msg1[] = "error opening file\n"; write( 1, msg1, sizeof( msg1 ) - 1 );  Use multiple variable names like msg1, msg2, etc so you can easily use have more than one message.

What does find_newline_eof() do? How does it detect EOF? What happens if the input file doesn't end with newline?

None of the code after return (bytes_readed); in read_newpiece() ever executes. So it never copied into buffer.

You never compiled what you posted here without headers.  BUFFER_SIZE is not defined.

Use STDOUT_FILENO instead of hardcoding magic value 1.

Why are you outputting error messages with write(1, ...) when you evidently have printf among the functions available to you?

To speed things up, maybe you should edit your question and post a list of standard functions that you are (or are not) allowed to use.

@JohnBollinger i am not allowed to use printf, just used fro trying debug: the functions i am allowed to use is write, malloc, free and read

No printf? What about sprintf?

That's 1. dumb restriction, and 2. confusing question.  In any case, it's not relevant for the error most likely so drop that restriction and fix it after you know what the issue is.

ft_strlen(), str_realloc() are missing.  I am going to vote closing this for lacking focus.

foo = realloc(foo, ..) leaks to memory leak if realloc fails.

static char *buffer = NULL is going to be trouble when you malloc it.

@AllanWind  literally my first post here. but go on, i am trying to respond and edit in order to be more understandable

You should do the [tour], if you haven't yet, and read [mre], [ask] to get a sense of what we expect of you.  We are here to help.  Also, telling me to chill is  rude when I am going out of my way to try to help you.

"I am not allowed to use functions" – that's in the submitted work. Start off with as many standard functions as you need, get the code working, and only then replace them with home-made functions.

I suggest you rethink the design of dynamically allocating static char * buffer in get_next_line() and resizing in read_newpiece() as it's tricky to reason about.  It also leaks memory.

BUFFER_SIZE is presumably a compile time constant.  I would use an static_assert() or just assume it's reasonable.  Similar as you have a fd check in main() you don't need to check that for every line.

@AllanWind Use STDOUT_FILENO instead of hardcoding magic value 1. I dunno: "STDOUT_FILENO
Standard output value, stdout. Its value is 1."  So it's not a magic value. I'm usually a stickler for not using magic values, but this one isn't all that magical.

@AndrewHenle Yeah, that's a magic value, even if it's a constant defined by whatever higher power.  Reasonable people can disagree.  Let's say op is told to write stderr instead.  It's a lot easier to grep for STDOUT_FILENO than 1.

@AllanWind And integers are also defined by another higher power.  If you follow that logic to its inevitable conclusion, every number needs to be replaced by a #define.  "Nope, you can't use 3 - it's a magic number.  You have to #define THREE 3!", ad naseum.

@AndrewHenle Maybe the definition of magic value helps? "A unique value with unexplained meaning or multiple occurrences which could (preferably) be replaced with a named constant". Your argument must be that because the standard defines it is indeed explained.  My pragmatic response was grepability.  It's kinda a tangent so I will let you have the last word if you want to disagree.

@AllanWind  i manage to work on what you said, the return (bytes_readed) in the middle of function was just a lapse, i forgot to comment, i used to test it. but in fact when the content in the file was all readed, the get_next_line returned a empty string when it should to return NULL, causing the infinite loop, i also try to address the possible leaks and i run valgrind --leak-check=full and it was everything ok, i will work on improvements to the whole code now. thanks for patience and the help

BUFFER_SIZE was just not pick by my ctrl+c, but it was defined with the header files at the top #define BUFFER_SIZE 42(should work with any number)
